# How to solve Python Pandas assign error when creating new column

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, assign

I have a dataframe containing home descriptions:

```
description
0   Beautiful, spacious skylit studio in the heart...
1   Enjoy 500 s.f. top floor in 1899 brownstone, w...
2   The spaceHELLO EVERYONE AND THANKS FOR VISITIN...
3   We welcome you to stay in our lovely 2 br dupl...
4   Please don’t expect the luxury here just a bas...
5   Our best guests are seeking a safe, clean, spa...
6   Beautiful house, gorgeous garden, patio, cozy ...
7   Comfortable studio apartment with super comfor...
8   A charming month-to-month home away from home ...
9   Beautiful peaceful healthy homeThe spaceHome i...
```

I'm trying to count the number of sentences on each row (using `sent_tokenize` from `nltk.tokenize`) and append those values as a new column, `sentence_count`, to the `df`. Since this is part of a larger data pipeline, I'm using pandas `assign` so that I could chain operations.

I can't seem to get it to work, though. I've tried:

```
df.assign(sentence_count=lambda x: len(sent_tokenize(x['description'])))
```

and

```
df.assign(sentence_count=len(sent_tokenize(df['description'])))
```

but both raise the following errro:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I've confirmed that each row has a `dtype` of `str`. Perhaps it's because `description` has `dtype('O')`?

What am I doing wrong here? Using a `pipe` with a custom function works fine here, but I prefer using `assign`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x['description']` when you pass it to `sent_tokenize` in the first example is a `pandas.Series`. It's not a string. It's a Series (similar to a list) of strings.

So instead you should do this:

```py
df.assign(sentence_count=df['description'].apply(sent_tokenize))
```

Or, if you need to pass extra parameters to `sent_tokenize`:

```py
df.assign(sentence_count=df['description'].apply(lambda x: sent_tokenize(x)))
```

Comment: That's what did originally, but I'm looking for a way to chain `sent_tokenize` without `df['counts'] =`. Is there a way to make it part of a chained operation?

Comment: Yes! There is. I didn't realize that's what you were trying to do with `df.assign` :) Check the answer now.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Just one thing for future readers: I think `x['description']` should be `df['description']`. You get an error otherwise

Comment: I assume this last comment is now incorporated.

Comment: One other question, presumably df['description'] could only refer to columns in the original df, not new columns that come in the chained operations.